# need to convert object to JSON value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have following request body,

```
{
    name1:"john,doe",
    name2:"peter,frank"
}
```

I need to get output as following

```
{
    "name1":["john","doe"],
    "name2":["peter","frank"],
}
```

I am trying to use array methods.

Comment: your given data is not valid.

Comment: What do you mean that's the body? In JS that's the comma operator, the first values are inaccessible. In JSON it's not syntactically valid at all.

Comment: Your request body looks very strange. Why don't you use JSON for your requests? Or XML, YAML, ...

Comment: edited the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the object with [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement), and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the value into an array. Then [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the object.

```js
const res = {
  name1:"john,doe",
  name2:"peter,frank"
};

for (const key in res) {
  res[key] = res[key].split(',');
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` and iterate over every key value and convert value into array and get back the new object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const o = { name1: "john,doe", name2: "peter,frank" },
      result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([key, val]) => ([key, val.split(',')]))
      );
console.log(result);
```